# Java Gregorian Calendar Returns Wrong Month

Tags: java, calendar, gregorian-calendar

So I been at this for a few hours now and it returns the correct Year, and Day but for some odd reason it returns the wrong month. I'm sure its a simple fix but I can't seem to figure it out.

```
package gregoriancalendar;

import java.util.GregorianCalendar;

public class Calendar8_5 {



public static void main(String[] args){

GregorianCalendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar();
System.out.println("Current Year, Month & Date: ");
System.out.println("Year is " + calendar.get(1));
System.out.println("Month is " + calendar.get(2));
System.out.println("Day is " + calendar.get(5));


calendar.setTimeInMillis(1234567898765L);
//Elapse Time
System.out.println("Set Value of 1234567898765L");
System.out.println("Year is " + calendar.get(1));
System.out.println("Month is " + calendar.get(2));
System.out.println("Day is " + calendar.get(5));
   }
  }
```

Comment: Have you read the javadoc?

Comment: Probably because of this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/344380/why-is-january-month-0-in-java-calendar

Comment: Alright that makes more sense so calendar is 0-11 11 being december. Common sense would tell me to add 1 but I know that won't work and give me an odd result. So is there a work around this?

Comment: Why wouldn't it work to add 1?

Comment: Adding one results in the 111 or 49

Comment: @Kupcake69 What did you mean by `//Elapse Time`?

Comment: Duplicate: [Calendar returns wrong month](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1755199/642706)

Comment: Duplicate: [Creating java date object from year,month,day](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16499228/642706)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## tl;dr

To get a number 1-12 for current month:

```
LocalDate.now()
         .getMonthValue()
```

Better to specify your desired/expected time zone.

```
LocalDate.now( 
    ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" ) 
).getMonthValue()
```

Similarly call `.getYear()` and `.getDayOfMonth()`.

## Details

> it returns the wrong month

As others said, in `Calendar` the **months January-December are crazily numbered 0-11** rather than 1-12. One of many poor design decisions in the old date-time classes. Those classes are now legacy, supplanted by the java.time classes.

> So is there a work around this?

Yes, there is a workaround. Use a good date-time library rather than the mess that is java.util.Date/Calendar. The modern way is with the java.time classes.

### Current moment

Time zone is crucial in getting the current date and time. For any given moment the date and wall-clock time vary by zone.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" );
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.now( z );
```

You can interrogate for the various components such as year, month number, localized name of month via [`Month`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Month.html) enum, and day-of-month.

```
System.out.println ( "Current: " + zdt );
System.out.println( "Year is " + zdt.getYear() );
System.out.println( "Month is " + zdt.getMonthValue() );
System.out.println( "Month name is " + zdt.getMonth().getDisplayName( TextStyle.FULL , Locale.CANADA_FRENCH ) );  // Or Locale.US, Locale.ITALY, etc.
System.out.println( "Day is " + zdt.getDayOfMonth() );
```

> Current: 2016-12-14T04:54:44.802-05:00[America/Montreal]
>
> Year is 2016
>
> Month is 12
>
> Month name is décembre
>
> Day is 14

See [live code in IdeOne.com](http://ideone.com/aIuHNs).

If you only care about the date and not the time-of-day, use the `LocalDate` class.

```
LocalDate.now( z );
```

## Specific moment

You can specify a moment as a count of milliseconds since the [epoch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epoch_(reference_date)) of first moment of 1970 in UTC.

```
long input = 1_234_567_898_765L ;
Instant instant = Instant.ofEpochMilli( input );
```

> instant.toString(): 2009-02-13T23:31:38.765Z

The `Z` in that output is short for `Zulu` and means [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time).

You can assign a time zone to adjust into a particular wall-clock time.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" );
ZonedDateTime zdt = instant.atZone( z );
```

> zdt.toString(): 2009-02-13T18:31:38.765-05:00[America/Montreal]

See [live code in IdeOne.com](http://ideone.com/h8ngrr).

I do *not* recommend exchanging date-time data this way. Better to serialize to text in [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) formats. For example: `2009-02-13T23:31:38.765Z`

---

## About java.time

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8) and [**SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9) and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - The [*ThreeTenABP*](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts ***ThreeTen-Backport*** (mentioned above) for Android specifically.
  - See [*How to use…*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [ThreeTen-Extra](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

---

## Old Answer - Joda-Time

Update: The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

- Use [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) 2.3 now.
- In the future, with Java 8, consider moving to [JSR 310: Date and Time API](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310) which supplants the Date/Calendar classes and is inspired by Joda-Time.

## Example Code

### Today

```java
// © 2013 Basil Bourque. This source code may be used freely forever by anyone taking full responsibility for doing so.
// import org.joda.time.*;

// Generally best to be explicit about time zone rather than depend on default.
DateTimeZone denverTimeZone = DateTimeZone.forID( "America/Denver" );
java.util.Locale locale = Locale.FRANCE;

DateTime now = new DateTime( denverTimeZone );

System.out.println( "Current Year, Month & Day for: " + now );
System.out.println( "Year is " + now.year().getAsText( locale ) );
System.out.println( "Month is " + now.monthOfYear().getAsText( locale ) );
System.out.println( "Day is " + now.dayOfMonth().getAsText( locale ) );
System.out.println(); // blank line.
```

When run…

```
Current Year, Month & Day for: 2013-12-04T01:58:24.322-07:00
Year is 2013
Month is décembre
Day is 4
```

### Some Day

```java
// Not generally a good idea to focus on integers for working with date-time, but you asked for it.
DateTime someDateTime = new DateTime( 1234567898765L, DateTimeZone.UTC );

System.out.println( "Set Value of 1234567898765L is: " + someDateTime );
System.out.println( "Year is " + someDateTime.year().getAsText( locale ) );
System.out.println( "Month is " + someDateTime.monthOfYear().getAsText( locale ) );
System.out.println( "Day of month is " + someDateTime.dayOfMonth().getAsText( locale ) );
System.out.println( "Day of week is " + someDateTime.dayOfWeek().getAsText( locale ) );
System.out.println( "Day of year is " + someDateTime.dayOfYear().getAsText( locale ) );
```

When run…

```
Set Value of 1234567898765L is: 2009-02-13T23:31:38.765Z
Year is 2009
Month is février
Day of month is 13
Day of week is vendredi
Day of year is 44
```

---

P.S. I just got the chills down my back when I noticed your arbitrarily chosen Long resulted in Friday The Thirteenth!

Comment: Basil, Thanks for the full explanation and example of Joda Time. This really helps a lot. I will be playing with this a bit and see how it works out :)

Comment: @Kupcake69 The more you know about Joda-Time, the more you’ll like it. Joda-Time is one of the best reasons to use Java. Search StackOverflow for `joda` to find many examples and tips. Working with date-time is often tricky and confusing, but Joda-Time is a big help.

Answer (score 3):

For some insane reason, [Calendar](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html) class uses a zero-based index for month (Jan==0, Feb==1, etc), but all other date parts are one-based (matching their actual numbers).

Presumably it was done in some lame attempt at an enumeration, but it's just stupid.

My advice is to never use Calendar. Use [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) instead.

Comment: Thank you this really helps. reading and doing some more research I see theres a bit of a preference to using Joda-Time.

Answer (score 1):

Try using new date and time library provided by [Java 8](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html), which are inspired by Joda-Time and they are easy to use. It also solved problem of having month starting with 0.