# How Make operation on time

Tags: java

i have a string like this on my java code:

> 17:00

I want to make a subtraction using a constant integer

```
 public static final int MAX_DUREE_TRAVAIL_JOUR = 10;
```

When i do this:

```
Integer.parseInt("17:00") - ConstantesIntervention.MAX_DUREE_TRAVAIL_JOUR
```

I have this error:

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "17:00"
```

Thx.

Comment: yup.. coz `:` is not an integer

Comment: You should use the `split` method of the `String` class to separate out the hours from the minutes, then parse each part separately.

Answer (score 2):

What are you expecting to happen?  17:00 is not a valid string representation of an integer.

You probably want to use a [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) to parse the string as a `Date` and do the time arithmetic on that.

Alternatively, take a look at the [JodaTime library](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) which provides much better handling of dates/times.

Answer (score 1):

17:00 cant be to converted to an integer.

Answer (score 0):

The [answer by Ajai](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20371490/642706) is correct.

Some advice: When working with dates and times, work with dates and times (not strings and integers). Meaning use date-time classes.

Use a good date-time library (not the mess that is java.util.Date/Calendar).

- Use [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) 2.3 now.
- In the future, with Java 8, consider moving to [JSR 310: Date and Time API](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310) which supplants the Date/Calendar classes and is inspired by Joda-Time.

---

P.S. Mercer, Joda-Time even knows how to speak *français*. See [another answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20370992/642706) today for an example.

Answer (score 0):

Because 17:00 is not a Correct integer.You should divide the string and use Integer.parse() then according to your business logic use those integers.