# Why is the month returned by calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH) the previous month and not the current one?

Tags: java, date, calendar

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
String data = calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY) + ":" + calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE) + " " + calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) + "-"
        + calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH) + "-"
        + calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
System.out.println(data);
```

nad print: 23:3 15-6-2015 but today is 23:03 15-7-2015
Month is previous and how to change 23:3 to 23:03 ?

Comment: 0 offset vs 1 offset

Comment: possible duplicate of [Calendar returns wrong month](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1755199/calendar-returns-wrong-month)

Comment: @dekros Please search StackOverflow before posting. This topic has been addressed many times before.

Answer (score 1):

It's completely non-intuitive and annoying, but that's how the API was designed; the value returned when you ask for a month is zero-based; you have to add one to it to get the "real" month-number.

Check out the documentation for the [`Calendar.MONTH`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#MONTH) field:

> Field number for get and set indicating the month. This is a calendar-specific value. The first month of the year in the Gregorian and Julian calendars is `JANUARY` **which is 0**; the last depends on the number of months in a year. (emphasis mine)

Also, instead of building the string out by hand it would be far easier to use something like [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html); you won't run into this issue then, and you will also be able to print out the time as `23:03`:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm dd-MM-yyyy");
sdf.setTimeZone(calendar.getTimeZone());
System.out.println(dateFormat.format(calendar.getTime()));
```

Comment: ok i make something like this (calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH)+1) + "-"
and this work but how to change this 23:3 to 23:03

Comment: @dekros Use `SimpleDateFormat`. I have added an example.